# In Zig, how do you tell if a frame represents a fully executed function?

Tags: zig

In Zig (currently using 0.7.1), suppose for some reason you don't have any good way to design code which always has exactly one `resume` for every `suspend`. Is there any supported way to detect at runtime that a given frame has or has not been executed to completion?

```
// overly simplistic example designed to illustrate the problem
pub fn main() void {
    var frame = async amain(2);
    resume frame;
    resume frame;

    // panic/UB -- resume async function which already returned
    // 
    // we would prefer to have some kind of check which could allow
    // us to detect at runtime that the following resumption is illegal
    resume frame;
}

fn amain(ubound: i32) void {
    var i: i32 = 0;
    while (i < ubound) : (i += 1) {
        suspend;
    }
}
```

If I log the raw bytes of those frame structs (which as far as I can tell are opaque and don't support field access? I'm a little new to Zig), then it seems pretty obvious that a portion of the frame is dedicated to marking whether it has returned:

```
[70, 3a, 23, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00]
[70, 3a, 23, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00]
[70, 3a, 23, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, ff, 02, 00, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 00]
```

Blindly reading that data seems a little reckless however, and I'd feel a lot more comfortable if I knew the struct layout were guaranteed or that there were some builtin way to uncover that information.

Edit::

In particular, the problem that I'm trying to solve is that when designing an event loop (e.g. when interfacing between JS and Zig/WASM) you seem to have to marry the implementation of an async function to the API of the event loop itself.

The built-in event loop, for example, has a `yield()` function precisely so that it can do the necessary bookkeeping to ensure that code has one resume per suspend, but as far as I can tell that's an unnecessary restriction since whether a frame has returned seems to be stored and readily accessible.

It's certainly possible that I'm misunderstanding the purpose of Zig's async/await, but I don't see any fundamental reason why a general purpose event loop capable of handling any async function (not just those adhering to a particular loop API) couldn't be written, but I'm struggling to see how that's possible without a little more runtime introspection than the docs indicate is available.

Comment: Your quest might be related to [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) which states that such questions are undecidable (at compilation time)

Comment: I am also new to Zig and have the same question. At the moment I have solved it  passing as a parameter a struct with var bool IsEnded, I set to TRUE after last suspend, but it would be great to query the frame itself if possible.

Comment: please [join the community](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Community#discord) to fix and discuss these kind of questions as the api and details are still in flux/design phase.

Comment: @Jay-Pi https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Community#stack-overflow ;)

Comment: @Jay-Pi I tried a time or two to ask about this on IRC and was met with crickets. Is there a "canonical" (for lack of a better word) community to start with? Reddit?

Comment: @HansMusgrave I am hanging out at the discord. Protty, lithdrew and haze are discussing on the showtime discord async stuff in a channel. You have probably seen prottys scheduling + async videos on the showtime.

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2022 there's an [open proposal](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/3164) for implementing this feature in the language. A workaround till then might still be manually reading the async frame header.